# Why doesn't my Apache LocationMatch directive work?

Tags: apache-2.4, cobbler

I need help getting apache's `LocationMatch` to work.

I'm trying to set up a cobbler server, and it requires SSL by default. I want to rewrite so that people can use http://server/cobbler_web instead as well as the https://server/cobbler_web, and it will bring them to the same page. I am trying to use `LocationMatch` to match `cobbler_web` in the URL, like so:

```
### Force SSL only on the WebUI
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <LocationMatch "^/cobbler_web/">
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
   </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

but no matter what I try on the LocationMatch line, nothing works. I've tried the line you see above, and also `.*cobbler_web.*`, and `^/cobbler_web/.*`, amongst others. No joy.

If I remove the `LocationMatch` entirely, it works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're turning on the rewrite engine anyway, just use that to match the location:

```
   RewriteRule ^/cobbler_web/ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: That didn't work. Neither did this: `RewriteRule "^/cobbler_web/" https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]` . I got "403 Forbidden" results.

Comment: Just to make sure, you removed the LocationMatch block, right? Anyway, 403 could be generated from a number of reasons, you need to have a look at the error log, and also enable mod_rewrite log and see what's going on.

Comment: Yes I removed the LocationMatch block. To be clear: Put it in, fail. Take it out, success. It is as simple as that... for me. I will look at the logs you suggest. I didn't see anything useful in the error log but I'll check again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this configuration doesn't work, but in this simple case plain old `<Location "/cobbler_web/">` should be enough.

Comment: That doesn't work either. :-(

Comment: Strange, don't you have a reverse proxy server in front that could potentially alter the URI?

Comment: No, I am accessing a virtual machine that is running on my desktop machine right now.